# Laravel 5.2 soft delete does not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, soft-delete

I am have simple app with a table post and model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use SoftDeletes;
class Post extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'post';

   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

   protected $softDelete = true;

}
```

I am trying to make example of soft delete and i am using route just for example route.php:

```
<?php
use App\Post;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
Route::get('/delete', function(){
    $post = new Post();
    Post::find(12)->delete();

});
```

I have a column "created_at" created with migration:

```
    Schema::table('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

, but instead of adding time to this column, when I run the site it deletes the row with selected id. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Try moving the `use SoftDeletes;` inside the class. I think documentation suggests that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `SoftDeletes` trait inside your model like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
   use SoftDeletes;

   protected $table = 'post';

   protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Now you, are not applying trait, so obviously it doesn't work.

In addition you have unnecessary piece of code in your routes file. It should look like this:

```
<?php
use App\Post;

Route::get('/delete', function(){
    Post::find(12)->delete();
});
```

Comment: Thank YOU very much :) .

Comment: Ah, thanks it worked for me using `delete()` method while I was trying to use `trashed()` method which has been shown on official documentation to for `softDelete` but that was not doing this work, always returning `false`

Comment: Still can delete permanently with  `forceDelete`  method ;)