# soft delete not working when $dateFormat="U"

Tags: laravel, date-format, soft-delete

Im trying to import softDelete to current project. In migration file i added:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

In model. I got this:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

But deleting not working as i expected.

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '1579188678' for column 'deleted_at'

So my question is how can i use deleted_at as unix time or how to use deleted_at column as timestamp when `protected $dateFormat = 'U';` this was still exist. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 soft delete does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518175/laravel-5-2-soft-delete-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use the Unix timestamp as format, you can't use the `->sofDeletes()` and `->timestamps()` methods in migration, you need to set them yourself as integers

```php
$table->integer('created_at')->nullable();
$table->integer('updated_at')->nullable();
$table->integer('deleted_at')->nullable();
```

Comment: well thats so easy. I was shamed a little bit :) I thought hardest ways. like
protected $dates = ['deleted_at' => 'string'];
etc. Thanks sir.